# Simple generator of pseudo-random permutations of variable length short sequence

Tags: randomness, number-theory, pseudo-random-generators, modular-arithmetic, random-number-generator

The problem in front of me is to write a function (from scratch) to permute n elements, where n is an argument. I decided to break it down to applying Knuth's shuffles algorithm, therefore I needed to write a pseudorandom number generator.

So now my task is to write a simple function `F(seed,n)` that will help me generate indices for the pseudorandom permutations of n elements. However, the function has to be extremely simple: My constraint is that I can only use the following operators: +,-,*,/,%, specifically, no address access, binary encoding, bits selection etc. - only arithmetic on numbers. That is fine, I went for linear congruental generators and implemented a `(a*x+c)%m` procedure.

As I started testing `F(seed,2)` it immediately went apparent that the results oscilate between zero and one with a period of two.

My problem is: how can I adjust `F` to avoid that behavior? Maybe I should generate the n-permutations in a different manner?

In practice, I am only interested in n=<32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The low bits of a linear congruential generator are notoriously weak. Try to use only the higher order bits. Normally this is done by bit operations, but you can discard the bottom $b$ bits by dividing by $2^b$ and rounding down.